# No primary or single unique constructor found for interface OAuth2AuthorizedClientService

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to receive the string form of an access token in a simple OAuth2 Spring application. It appears the best way to do this [is with OAuth2AuthorizedClientService](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github). However, I'm getting the following error whenever trying to use it:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService

at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:267) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:147) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
...
```

My project couldn't be simpler, I have a Main class, Config, and Controller. There are two endpoints; /home (permitAll) and /test (authenticated). **The above error occurs when requesting /test**.

Config (@Configuration):

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/test/**").authenticated()
            .mvcMatchers("/home/**").permitAll()
            // mvcMatchers more secure than antMatchers as it infers other things in path
            // regexMatchers allows you to use any regex for matching paths
        .and().oauth2Login();

    return http.build();
}

private ClientRegistration clientRegistration() {
    return CommonOAuth2Provider.GITHUB.getBuilder("github").clientId("<not sharing>")
            .clientSecret("<not sharing>")
            .scope("user:email").build();
}

@Bean 
public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRepository() {
     ClientRegistration clientReg = clientRegistration();
     
     return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(clientReg); 
}
```

Controller (@RestController):

```
@GetMapping("/home")
public String home() {
    return "home page";
}

@GetMapping("/test")
public OAuth2AuthenticationToken testToken(OAuth2AuthenticationToken token, 
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientService svc) {
    
    var t = svc.loadAuthorizedClient(token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), token.getName());
    System.out.println(t.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
    
    return token;
}
```

I figured my issue might be Maven dependencies. However, using the above article as a reference, it doesn't appear my dependencies should be an issue. They look as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using jdk-16.0.1. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the relevant OAuth2 identity provider configuration as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2login-sample-application-config)?

Comment: did you read the documentation? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#oauth2login-register-clientregistrationrepository-bean

Comment: @Toerktumlare yes. did you read my code? or my question?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, simple mistake. I passed OAuth2AuthorizedClientService as a param instead of autowiring it in the controller.

```
@Autowired
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService service;

@GetMapping("/home")
public String home() {
    return "home page";
}

@GetMapping("/test")
public OAuth2AuthenticationToken testToken(OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
    
    var t = service.loadAuthorizedClient(token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), token.getName());
    System.out.println(t.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
    
    return token;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for making the same mistakes I did!!